# How do I place text over a moving div without it being transformed

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations, css-transitions

I am in quite a pickle...

So here is my situation, I want to make a moving animation when the mouse hovers over it.

When this happens, I would like text that is layered over this div to remain in the same position.

In my setup, I have a parent div that controls the yellow div inside it when the mouse hovers over it. Also inside the parent div is the text that I would like to position over the edge of the yellow div and remain static during the animation.

html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Lorem</h1>
    <br>
    <h2>ipsum dolor</h2>
    <br><br><br>
    <div>
      <div id="yellow-con">
        <div><p><b>button</b></p></div>
        <div class="yellow"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

css:

```
p {
  display: inline;
  font-family: 'Crimson Text';
  color: #faf3dd;
  font-size:5vh;
  z-index: 2;
}

#yellow-con {
  background-color: #000000;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%
}

.yellow {
  display: inline-block;
  left: 20%;
  height: 7%;
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease;
  transform-origin: right;
  transform: scaleX(0px);
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #fccd34;
  z-index: 1;
}

#yellow-con:hover .yellow {
  transform: scaleX(.75);
}
```

This is what it is making

[image]

No matter what I do I simply cannot find a way to put the text over the moving divider without it:

1. Not staying on the same x plane as the moving div
2. Being transformed with the moving div

Answer (score 0):

Wish this is what you looking for. If you didn't want the text to move you should add position absolute to your yellow div and also relative position to your parent div. then you can position the yellow div as you want. Also, you should put the width: 80%; before your scaleX(0) so that transform can work and also you should give the scaleX transform, 0 as a value, not 0px.

Run the snippet to see the result.

```css
p {
  display: inline;
  font-family: 'Crimson Text';
  color: #faf3dd;
  font-size:5vh;
  z-index: 2;
}

#yellow-con {
  background-color: #000000;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}

.yellow {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease;
  transform-origin: right;
  width: 80%;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  background-color: #fccd34;
  z-index: 1;
}

#yellow-con:hover .yellow {
  transform: scaleX(.75);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Lorem</h1>
    <br>
    <h2>ipsum dolor</h2>
    <br><br><br>
    <div>
      <div id="yellow-con">
        <div><p><b>button</b></p></div>
        <div class="yellow"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made a rough snippet for the use case please build on top of it.

```css
.relative{
  position:'relative';
  width:150px;
  height:50px;
}

.static{
  position:absolute;
}

.hoverable{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:yellow;
  transition:transform 1s;
}

.hoverable:hover{
  transform:translate(150px,0px);
}
```

```html
<div class='relative'>
<div class='static'>Static Text</div>
<div id='yellow' class='hoverable'/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
p {
  display: inline;
  font-family: 'Crimson Text';
  color: #faf3dd;
  font-size:5vh;
  z-index: 2;
}

/*added this class*/
.child-1 { 
  position: absolute;  
  z-index: 10;
}

#yellow-con {
  background-color: #000000;
  position: relative;
  height: 25px;
}

.yellow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease;
  transform-origin: right;
  width: 100%;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  background-color: #fccd34;
  z-index: 1;
}

#yellow-con:hover .yellow {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

#yellow-con:hover b {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <div id="yellow-con">
        <div class="child-1"><p><b>button</b></p></div>
        <div class="yellow"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```